# Array initialized with 0's

Tags: java

I created an array `int []array = new int[10];`

and didn't put any elements in it.

After when i tried to display the array using:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++) {

    System.out.print(array[counter] + " ");

}
```

The output is just: `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

I want it just with spaces. When i filed the array with a `char` space `' '` and output the array, i get `32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32`

Any help?

Comment: Because the default value for an `int` is 0. Read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: The space character *is* 32 in unicode.

Comment: do you even ASCII table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is a primitive, its default value is 0. When you try to store a `char` (another primitive) as an `int`, the space = 32.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring the array as `int[]`, you're telling the compiler that you want the array's contents to be treated as integers.  Numbers.  You can't then go and expect it to deal with things that are not numbers, such as space characters.  If you want to store characters in an array, you should declare it as `char[]`.

Even if you declare the array as `char[]`, it's not going to contain spaces by default.  You'll still need to put the spaces in explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Default value for int is already 0. You don't need to initialize for it to be 0. But if you want spaces you should create a char array and initialize each element to ' '.

Ex

```
char[] myArray = new char[10]

for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
{ myArray[i] = ' '; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have characters in the array you should use a `char[]` instead of an `int[]`. But still, you need to initialize it with blanks, the default initialization puts 0 into the array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Normal Java behavior. If you don't supply an initializer, or set the array's contents, they will be initialized to 0.

It sounds like you wanted

```
int[] array = new int[]{' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};
```

or

```
int[] array = new int[]{32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32};
```

Comment: Corrected. Thanks, ZouZou.